# Using external USB camera in Android P using API 28

Tags: android, android-camera, android-9.0-pie

Today, Android P was released. I was wondering if there was any example of using 
`INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_EXTERNAL` which is available from [API 28](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata?authuser=3#INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_EXTERNAL)  to get an external USB webcam to work with a camera application.

Some people have tried doing similar things before such as https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=snapexwebcam.com&hl=en_US and https://github.com/jwoolston/Android-Webcam, but they do not seem to have used Google's external camera API to achieve this.

Comment: I've tried connecting a UVC Camera on my Pixel with Android P, and it only list 2 camera, front and back, without the connected USB camera so my guess is it isn't supported yet. Also, the built in camera app doesn't identify external UVC camera.

Comment: @OrenBengigi Yes, I had the same experience with my Pixel 2. I was looking for a camera app that did identify the external UVC camera, as I am looking to add support for it in my own app.

Comment: anyone reach for a solution to this